# Roll a dice infinitely many times, what is the probability of getting a 5 before a 6

Tags: probability, probability-theory, dice

My proof: For all possible events, based on the order of appearance between 5 and 6.l, they can be categorised into 2 groups.

$A:$ event with 5 appear before 6
$A^{c}:$ event with 6 appear before 5

And the union of $A$ and $A^{c}$ should be all possible events.

So $P(A) + P(A^{c}) = 1$

The last step: by symmetry, number of events that have 5 before 6 is the same as that for 6 before 5.

So $P(A) = P(A^{c}) = 0.5$

However, this last step I am not sure  how to write out a formal proof to support my intuition for the symmetry. I think I need to evaluate the cardinality $A$ and $A^{c}$ but not sure how to. So I need help here.

Comment: Symmetry does the job...Interchanging all the $5's$ and $6's$ in all the toss sequences, exchanges all the paths in which $5$ wins with the paths in which $6$ wins.  If you are worried about the existence of the limit, note that the probability that you don't see either a $5$ or a $6$ in $n$ tosses is $\left(\frac 46\right)^n$ which goes to $0$ for large $n$.

Comment: @lulu thanks for your comment. Yes the thing concerns me are the limit and infinity as i was not sure about how to express it

Comment: Right, so work out the probability, $p_n$ that you see a $5$ before a $6$ in $n$ tosses.  Of course that equals the probability that you see $6$ before $5$ in $n$ chances.  Now $2p_n$ will be slightly less than $1$, reflecting the small chance that you see neither.  Now let $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Beware: There are events in which either 5 or 6 or both never appear.

Comment: You can find such a problem and many other similar problems in Ross's textbook on probability theory, chapter 3.

Comment: It's a very beautiful proof!

Comment: Formally, you should partition the space in three events: 5 before 6, 6 before 5, and no 5s nor 6s. The two events you mention do not completely cover all the cases, since some rolls will produce no 5 and no 6. Then you prove that the "no 5s nor 6s" case has zero probability. Then you can continue by symmetry as you did.

Comment: The faces of a die have no identity except the label. Relabeling them, exchanging 5 and 6, cannot change the outcome. The events must be symmetrical.

Comment: "Dice" is plural.  The singular is "die".  You can "roll a die", or you can "roll several dice".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

to summarize the discussion in the comments:

For each $n\in \mathbb N$, let $p_n$ denote the probability that you see a $5$ before a $6$ in no more than $n$ tosses.  Of course, by symmetry, $p_n$ is also the probability that you see $6$ before $5$ within $n$ tosses.  These won't add to $1$, indeed, $1-2p_n$ is the probability you see neither $5$ nor $6$ in $n$ tosses.  Thus $$1-2p_n=\left( \frac 46\right)^n\implies p_n=\frac 12-\frac 12\times \left( \frac 46\right)^n$$

Letting $n$ tend to $\infty$ then yields the desired result.

Answer (score 14):

*Different method:*
$\displaystyle P(A_n)=\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{n-1}$, where $A_n$ is the event that you get a 5 in the n-th roll and that you haven't gotten either 5 or 6 before the n-th roll. $\displaystyle\frac{1}{6}$ is the probability of getting a 5 in a roll, and $\displaystyle\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{n-1}$ is the probability of not getting 5 or 6 before the n-th roll. From here $\displaystyle P(A)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty P(A_n)=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{n-1}=\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{4}{6}}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 12):

Ignore the scores that are not $5$ or $6$. So we have a two-sided die (i.e. a coin). So the probability of getting $5$ before $6$ is $1/2$.

Comment: NB: we have a two sided die *in the limit*. In the finite case, we may have no 5s or 6s, so not a coin. But provided we're only looking at the infinite case, we can be confident the 5 and 6 have appeared with probability 1.

Answer (score 4):

Another method:

Let $x$ be the probability that 5 appears before 6 in an infinite number of tosses. Let's consider the first toss in this experiment of infinite tosses. For event $A$ to be true, you must either observe a 5 in the first toss, or observe neither 5 or 6 in the first toss and 5 must appear before 6 in the subsequent tosses. Note that the subsequent tosses is also an infinite sequence, and hence the probability for 5 to appear before 6 in those tosses is again $x$. Hence, we can write the following equation: $$\frac 1{6}+\frac 4{6}(x)=x$$
Solving the above gives the answer as $x=0.5$.

Answer (score 3):

The proof you suggest is almost correct, there are only a few details to iron out. At least the intuition is correct.

The first detail is that the set of all issues can actually be partitioned into these three events, not just the first two:

- Event A "5 appears before 6";
- Event B "6 appears before 5";
- Event C "There are no 5 and 6 at all".

You didn't mention C, presumably because you had the correct intuition that its probability is $P(C) = 0$. But it needs to be mentioned if you want to partition the universe into disjoint events.

Because it's a partition, $P(A) + P(B) + P(C) = 1$. And because $P(C) = 0$, it follows that $P(A) + P(B) = 1$, which you correctly stated. Note that $P(B) = 1 - P(A)$, and yet we cannot write $B = A ^c$ since there are three events in the partition.

Your last step, the symmetry, is correct. In fact I would argue that it is much better to use symmetry rather than to carry out any complicated calculations as was done in some other answers.

However, you used the words "cardinality" and "number". This is incorrect. You should use the word "probability" instead. By symmetry, events $A$ and $B$ have the same probability, $P(A) = P(B)$.

Cardinality arguments are not helpful here. It is true that $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality, but that doesn't help at all. In fact, all three events $A$, $B$ and $C$ have the same cardinality $|A| = |B| = |C| = 2^{\aleph_0}$, and yet $C$ has a different probability: $P(A) = P(B) = \frac 1 2$ and $P(C) = 0$.